# How to use predifined protobuf type (i.e. "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto") with gRPC

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc

I'm trying to use `google/protobuf/timestamp.proto` in with gRPC plugin and Go. This is how I run `protoc`:

```
protoc -I  ./   ./*.proto --go_out=plugins=grpc:.
```

And this is my `.proto`:

```
#domain.proto
syntax = "proto3";
option java_multiple_files = true;
option java_package = "com.viant.xyz";
option java_outer_classname = "domain";

import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";

message Foo {
    Timestamp modifiedTime = 1;
    ...
}
```

I'm seeing the following errors:

```
domain.proto: Import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto" was not found or had errors.
domain.proto:44:5: "Timestamp" is not defined.
```

Am I missing something, or this is not yet supported?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not fully supported yet, but you can make it work by changing

```
message Foo {
    google.protobuf.Timestamp modifiedTime = 1;
    ...
}
```

and by fixing generated file import

```
import google_protobuf "google/protobuf/timestamp.pb"
```

to

```
import google_protobuf "github.com/golang/protobuf/ptypes/timestamp"
```

Answer (score 8):

Add `/usr/local/include` to include paths to use `/usr/local/include/google/api/timestamp.proto`:

```
protoc -I/usr/local/include -I. --go_out=plugins=grpc:. *.proto
```

As you can see in `timestamp.proto`, `Timestamp` exists in package `google.protobuf`, so you have to modify to use `Timestamp` like this:

```
message Foo {
    google.protobuf.Timestamp modifiedTime = 1;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 7):

In my case problem was in my Fedora 29 setup.

```
# Install Protoc compiler. By default it is 3.5.0 version
sudo dnf -y install protoc
```

This was my bad setup. So i fixed it with following steps. Pay attention to grayed out command lines too.

```
# Uninstall old 3.5.0 version
sudo dnf remove protobuf

# Make sure you grab the latest version
curl -OL  
https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/download/v3.6.1/protoc-3.6.1-linux-x86_64.zip
# Unzip
unzip protoc-3.6.1-linux-x86_64.zip -d protoc3
# Move protoc to /usr/local/bin/
sudo mv protoc3/bin/* /usr/local/bin/
# Move protoc3/include to /usr/local/include/
sudo mv protoc3/include/* /usr/local/include/
# Optional: change owner
sudo chown $USER /usr/local/bin/protoc
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/include/google
```

After this I am able to use:

```
import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";

message Session {
    google.protobuf.Timestamp create_time = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

After scratching my head for hours, I've found the issue.

My /usr/local/include directory doesn't have /google/protobuf files and without that once can't use predefined types. To solve this issue.

- curl -OL https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases/download/v3.2.0/protoc-3.2.0-linux-x86_64.zip
- unzip protoc-3.2.0-linux-x86_64.zip -d protoc3
- sudo mv protoc3/bin/* /usr/local/bin/
- sudo mv protoc3/include/* /usr/local/include/

Now you can simply use this command

protoc -I/usr/local/include -I. --go_out= {output_directory_path} {proto_file_path}

Answer (score 2):

If you are facing this inside an alpine docker image, make sure you do an `apk add protobuf-dev` before generating your files using `protoc`.

Answer (score 0):

I work around the problem by passing a `Mgoogle/protobuf/timestamp.proto=github.com/golang/protobuf/ptypes/timestamp` option to the Go grpc plugin.

In other words, I'm calling

```
protoc --go_out=plugins=grpc,Mgoogle/protobuf/timestamp.proto=github.com/golang/protobuf/ptypes/timestamp:outputdir input.proto
```

It's a bit of a hack. "Fortunately" I'm already using lots of `Mprotofile=go/pkg/import/path` parameters in my build setup, so it was easy to add.

Answer (score 0):

In windows, clone the repository:[protobuf](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf).

And run the command

```
protoc -I=$SRC_DIR -I=$YOUR_CLONE_LOCATION/protobuf/src --go_out=$DST_DIR $SRC_DIR/$SRC_FILE
```